# PHPUnit - assert method call order on different mocks

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I would like to test a method that just call a method of my entity object and persists it to the database.

```
public function setNameAndPersistObject($entityObject) {
    $entityObject->setName("John");
    $this->entityManager->persist($entityObject);
}
```

Both $entityObject and $entityManager are mocks, not actual objects.

I would like to test the call order of the called methods, to test that 'persist' gets called after 'setName', so the new name "John" gets saved in the database. How would I do that in PHPUnit?

Comment: I think you would want to use dummy data, dont actually persist it, or connect in a tank or anything.  use a flat file, call your dummy data with the test, and just validate that it can load, and or parse that data.  oh you want persist, ouch.  hmm, to a flat file?  sounds bad idea to connect in db.

Comment: Hmm, I think one way may be that I could mock the persist method, and set the returnCallback to clone the passed entityObject, and at the end compare it with the modified one. Maybe there is a more elegant way?

Comment: well, remember your not validating your data from your database, so you need to figure out how to mock them yes.  if you want test with actual data use dummy data.  if you want to pass an object, i would still use dummy data on a flat file and make it available in the same dir as your tests. so you can compare it with that flat file :-)  

In Hindsight, i guess you can get fancy and in your test, take advantage of mysql's tmp table to insert and compare test dummy data in one run i guess, etc.. ;-)  But thats getting fancy.

Comment: Abstracting from this case, provided that 'persists' could be another function, for example sleep(10). I would like to check the call order, not if the item gets persisted with the new name.

Comment: Also note, your not testing if mysql works, your testing if your code base can get to it, so as long as you pass in a valid object, and dont get an error on return, you dont really need to validate the data, as long as you validated it on its way out.  (your just testing functionality, in pieces, not the entire thing in one fell swoop test)

Comment: After some reserarch I will try to opt for Mockery [link](https://github.com/padraic/mockery) which allows this with ->ordered()

Answer (score 0):

Well... Not sure if this is the best/most clean way to do this, but recently I needed to check order between methods and this worked for me: you can simply have a variable and use it by reference on those methods. For example:

```
$name=null;
$mock1 = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(Entity::class)
    ->setMethods(['setName'])
    ->getMock();
$mock1->expects($this->any())
    ->method('setName')
    ->willReturnCallback(function($value) use (&$name) {
        $name = $value;
    });
$mock2 = $this
    ->getMockBuilder(EntityManager::class)
    ->setMethods(['persist'])
    ->getMock();
$mock2->expects($this->any())
    ->method('persist')
    ->willReturnCallback(function($object) use (&$name) {
        $this->assertNotNull($name);
    });
```

This should do the trick, at least. Notice it will fail if you create more mocks  using the same variable to save the name. Another option is to include in the first mock a function to return the value stored in name and call that function in the second mock. This will not be perfect but still a little bit safer.